# SO Jobs pagination at top too

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, pagination

The SO Jobs search results are not all that great. In order to pin point particular jobs of interest I use ctrl-f to search for a keyword on the page. For example, run a search of "Product Management" jobs. I got over 300 results that were intermixed with a number of software and other development positions. To help me process these quickly I hit ctrl-f "product" to find the 1 - 4 per page that would be applicable. I still have to scroll down to the bottom of the page to go to the next one. Having a next or the pagination at the top as well would allow me to quickly skip past screens of no interest. 
This would address my symptoms. The best result would be to improve the search results. 
Thanks.

Comment: What wasn't useful about the results? We can do a better job of making the results more relevant if you tell us why the results you received weren't relevant to you

Comment: In terms of the results, I just re-ran my search for "Product Manager" located anywhere. 381 results returned. 
  1. I see the featured opportunities. Gotta pay for the service somehow. That's cool.
  2. Follow on results: 
     a. 3rd listing is a PM position for Time Inc. located in NY 2w ago 
     b. 4th is a PM position at Conde Nast Intl. located in London 5d ago 
     c. 5th is for a firm in Germany from 3w ag   d. 6th is in Atlanta 2w ago
     e. 7th is in Boulder from 1w ago
     f. 24th is a Sr. PM listed 1w ago in CA
How are these sorted? Not by location, not by date either?

Comment: they're sorted by matches which takes aspects of your match preferences and uses them to weight attributes of each job. Aurélien wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@aurelien.gasser/a-dive-into-stack-overflow-jobs-search-62bc6e628f83) about it last week. I just looked into your match preferences and it looks like they weren't fully synced with another part of the system; perhaps take another look and see if there's any difference?

Comment: Second page results from comment above include:
Software Engineer, Product Development 12h ago, Product Manager 1w ago, Principal Product Development Engineer, 1w ago.
I get that the two positions sandwiching the PM position inclue product in the title so the're included. It however trains me to check all pages and listings because I cannot trust the results.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! That is spectacular. Wasn't aware that match settings were used. I had forgotten all about these since they were setup 6 - 18 months ago. Might be good to have some help on the page to this effect. "Seeing too many/little results check your match settings." Couple more things now. I see that the results are sorted by listing date. I added a match criteria of United States. There are still a few international listings coming through? My very specific location matches from earlier don't seem to be honored however? How about listing my criteria so I can turn on/off?

Comment: More... used "remote" as a filter and this culled results down to 42. Appears that the filters are being used like an AND function instead of an OR. If that makes sense. As a job seeker, I want to get the widest set of applicable results and then funnel it down based on what's returned. I want to know that I am not missing any possible jobs opportunities because of some search criteria. I however don't want to see positions that don't apply to me. This complicates my life and leads to frustration and not using the service. If I am not using the service employers will stop paying for listings.

Comment: more... not ranting, I value SO and am trying to provide some feedback to make this part more useful to all. As a product manager it's part of what I do.  Thanks.

Comment: I've not forgotten this, in the process of adding in some tooling to help diagnose some of these issues better.

Answer (score 1):

When I search for [product management](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=product+management) incognito I get a bunch of product manager and project manager jobs... I see just one developer job on the first page of results.

Even when I'm logged in and I mirror your match preferences the first page is entirely product/project management jobs. Can you detail what about the results isn't useful to you? Maybe some example jobs that appeared in the results that don't fit?

Also, you can search for [Product Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&dr=ProductManager) positions which filters the list to those that have been specifically marked as product management jobs. *Those*, though, do appear to have a problem; lots of them are development jobs. We're looking to see why that is now...